# Which is paypal cancel url response parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal sandbox account for testing purposes. When any user clicks on cancel and returns to the site, then which parameter will be received in the response?

[image]?

I am trying to change "You'll be able to see your order details before you pay" text to "You will be able to view your order details before you pay".

Can any one have idea, How to it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the cancel url, you don't get any parameters in the response. The cancel url is the url you set either in your account or in your button using "cancel_return" parameter  ([documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/))
2. You cannot change that text, is part of PayPal's site. However, you can contact PayPal and tell them a very good reason for them to change that text.